# I cant seem to save my json files in python?

Tags: python, json

My Json Code for this basic login system will not work and i am a bit confused plz help. it would be grately appreciated if you could.

-Thanks alot ^__^

'''

```
import json


sign_or_log = input('If you have an account on this repl please press 1 if you do not please press 2: ')

if sign_or_log == '2':
    username = input('Please enter your new Username: ')
    password = input('Please enter your new Password: ')
    write = [
      {
          "name": username,
          "password": password
      }
  ]
    file = open("data.json", "w+")
    file.write(json.dumps(write))
    file.close()
    print('Thank you for subminting your new account.')
    sign_or_log = input('If you have an account on this repl please press 1 if you do not please press 2: ')

    if sign_or_log == '1':
        login1 = input('Please enter your existing username: ')
        login2 = input('Please enter your existing password: ')
    try:
        file = open("data.json", "r")
        data = json.loads(file)
        file.close()
    except:
        print('Access Denied')
print(data)
```

'''

Comment: Can you narrow down the problem? "will not work" is very vague. I think you got a traceback message. If so, post it here. I think you should do `data = json.load(file)`.

Comment: I am not sure why it will not work so unfortunatly i cannot sorry

Comment: I ran your code a couple of times. I got "NameError: name 'data' is not defined" plus an "AccessDenied" error. Are you seeing something different?

Comment: No i get the same response

Comment: if you are getting an error, then post it. Your `except` is catching all exceptions, including vital information about your problem. Its a good idea to catch exceptions more narrowly.

Answer (score 1):

Use `json.dumps` to add to a json file like this:

```py
import json


def log_in():
    while True:
        login1 = input('Please enter your existing username: ')
        login2 = input('Please enter your existing password: ')

        if login1 != "" and login2 != "":
            break

    with open("data.json") as f: 
        data = json.load(f) # <-- Fixed the bug, again

    if data[login1] == login2:
        # User sucessfully logged in
    else:
        print('Access Denied')

def sign_up():
    username = input('Please enter your new Username: ')
    password = input('Please enter your new Password: ')
    user = {
        "name": username,
        "password": password
    }

    with open('data.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f)

    data.update(user)

    with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(data, f)

    print('Thank you for submitting your new account.')
    log_in()

message = 'If you have an account on this repl'
message += 'please press 1 if you do not please press 2:'

while True:
    sign_or_log = input(message)
    if sign_or_log == "1":
        log_in()
        break
    if sign_or_log == "2":
        sign_up()
        break
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/folders/71/yl6l7cv92yd4m3bhbw92jd840000gn/T/Jsno - test.py", line 17, in <module>
    data = json.load(f)
  File

Comment: Could you invite me to the repl? It could be a problem with your poetry.lock file. Here's my username @ClintonGraham.

Comment: Thanks for helping @ClintonGraham But the code is actually in vs code i just copied and pasted it from a repl i made a few days ago

Comment: In `log_in()`, the line `data = json.loads(file)` should be `data = json.load(file)` (drop the 's'). It's correctly done in `sign_up()` - `data = json.load(f)`.

Comment: Your current edit for the "fixed the bug" line in `log_in` is using `f` for the file pointer in `with open("data.json") as f` but `file` for the `data = json.loads(file) # <-- Fixed the bug`. And the `s` is back, it shouldn't be there. The correct line is `data = json.load(f)`.